# Ribbon button not firing event set by onAction when clicked 2

Tags: c#, xml, ms-office, vsto, ribbon

I'm currently working on office ribbon customisation, but I cannot succeed to display a messageBox when I click on a simple button.
I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674575/ribbon-button-not-firing-event-set-by-onaction-when-clicked) post, but signature looks fine. Moreover, even if I do exactly the same as it's specified on MSDN reference ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866(v=vs.100).aspx)), can't get results.

Here is my XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" >
      <ribbon>
        <tabs>
          <tab id="TEST" label="TEST">
            <group id="group1" label="Example">
              <button id="myButton" label="myButton" onAction="MyButtonOnAction" />
            </group>
          </tab>
        </tabs>
      </ribbon>
    </customUI>
```

And C#:

```
using [...]

namespace MyRibbonAddIn
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override Office.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new MyRibbon();
        }


        public void MyButtonOnAction(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            if (control.Id == "myButton")
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Button clicked!");
            }
        }


        *Code généré par VSTO*
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What is in your `MyRibbon` class? Try to move the button handler inside the `MyRibbon` class

Comment: Thank you, it works ! I hadn't thought about it even if it was obvious... Well done :)